# Two interpretations of Chaos?

Tags: definition, chaos-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Broadly speaking, I cannot pin down what is meant by Chaos. I understand that (informally) if a dynamical system is highly sensitive to initial input data then this system is said to be chaotic. Eg the famous Lorenz Equations.
However, I have come across the following definition from [theencyclopediaofmath.org](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Chaos) which states 
"Chaos describes a situation where typical solutions (or orbits) of a differential equation (or typical evolutions of some other model describing deterministic evolution) do not converge to a stationary or periodic function (of time) but continue to exhibit a seemingly unpredictable behaviour."
These two broad definitions seem to mean different things. Can anybody clear any of this up?

Comment: The two definitions are closely related. If arbitary close start values will eventually lead to totally different behaviours, this basically is what is described with the second definition. In practice that means, even if we assume a deterministic behaviour and that we know the starting configuration with a ridiculous high accuracy, we still would be unable to predict the long-term behaviour.